# How to archive an object in one View Controller and then unarchive it in another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I have an object "School" with a mutable array property "favoritesArray" and an NSString property "name".

I have 2 view controllers "HomeViewController" and "FavoritesTableViewController".

In my HomeViewController when a button is tapped this method is called:

```
self.school=[[School alloc]init]; 
[self.school.favoritesArray addObject:self.school.name];
 NSData *schoolData=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.school];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:schoolData forKey:@"schoolData"];
```

Then in my "FavoritesTableViewController" I attempt to unarchive the previously archived "school" object so I can access the "favoritesArray".

when a button is tapped in my "FavoritesTableViewController"  this method is called:

```
NSData *dataRetrieved=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"schoolData"];
School *schoolTwo=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRetrieved];
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)schoolTwo.favoritesArray.count);
```

However it logs 0  meaning it didn't unarchive the object that was archived in the "HomeViewController".

How do I unarchive the object that was archived in a separate view controller?

Comment: If exactly the same code works on the same ViewController, there must be something else, can you show the code of your ´School´ class?

Comment: @rivtracks have you got any solution for this, I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`School`must implement `NSCoding` for `NSKeyedArchiver` to be able to serialize it.

See http://nshipster.com/nscoding/ for a good introduction to NSCoding and NSKeyedArchiver.

Comment: If it was not implementing NSCoding it would throw an exception, instead of loggin a zero count!

Comment: I did implement NSCoding. It works perfectly when I unarchive it on the same view controller.

Comment: To me, it should work. Maybe you're seeing the same object when you unserialize in the same view controller? Could you show us the init, initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder methods for School?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you did was right, I think you forgot to initialise the mutable Array.

```
self.school=[[School alloc]init];
self.school.favoritesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.school.favoritesArray addObject:self.school.name];
```

Comment: To me, this should be done inside School init method.

Answer (score 0):

In your School `NSObject` where you have implemented the `NSCoding` protocol, have you encoded every objects you have in it? Its necesary to do that, because you are trying to archive the `School` object